# Wordpress ajax pagination for comments

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am calling in my Wordpress comments from the database and displaying them using a custom query, then using Wordpress' `paginate_links()` function to paginate my comments. My code:

```
<div class="commentsWrap">
<div id="comments" class="commentBoxesWrap">
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
     $querystr = " SELECT comment_content, commentmeta1.meta_value 
     AS comment_name, commentmeta2.meta_value 
     AS comment_country 
     FROM $wpdb->comments, $wpdb->commentmeta 
     AS commentmeta1, $wpdb->commentmeta 
     AS commentmeta2 
     WHERE $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta1.comment_id 
     AND $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta2.comment_id 
     AND commentmeta1.meta_key = 'comment_name' 
     AND commentmeta2.meta_key = 'comment_country' 
     AND $wpdb->comments.comment_approved = 1 ";

     $total_query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${querystr}) AS combined_table";
     $total = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
     $items_per_page = 4;
     $page = isset( $_GET['paged'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['paged'] ) : 1;
     $offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
     $comment_info =  $wpdb->get_results($querystr .  "ORDER BY $wpdb->comments.comment_date DESC LIMIT ${offset}, $items_per_page");

    echo '<ul class="commentsList">';
    // display the results
    foreach($comment_info as $info) { 
          echo '<li class="commentBox"><p>"' . $info->comment_content . '"</p><h6>' . $info->comment_name . ', ' . $info->comment_country . '</h6></li>'; 
    }
     echo '</ul>';
    ?>

     </div>  <!-- //commentBoxesWrap -->
     <?php
     echo '<div class="commentPagination">';
     echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
        'format' => '',
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
        'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
        'current' => $page
    ));
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
    </div>  <!-- //commentsWrap -->
```

This works fine and outputs a numbered pagination, however, I need to ajax the comments when I click the pagination. With a bit of research I managed to come up with this js code:

```
$('.commentsWrap').on('click', '.commentPagination a', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var link = $(this).attr('href');
     $('.commentsWrap').load(link + '.commentsWrap');
});
```

What this does though is load the entire page by ajax rather than the comments section! Can anybody help me please??

Thanks.

Comment: you are misssing a div </div>  <!-- //commentsWrap --> in the code.

Comment: It's there at the top in the actual code, I just forgot to paste it into my question

Comment: you can use infine scroll plugin also [https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/](here )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the pagination of comments. I have used jquery for this. You will need to change the url of ajax page url and loader image source.  Try to add this below you code. This code will only work if your pagination is right and working.

```
<div class="loadmorediv">

        <button id="loadmorebutton" style="padding:15px 25px;">More</button>

        <button id="no_morebutton" style="padding:15px 25px;">No more</button>

        </div> <!-- //commentsWrap -->


        <div class="row" style="text-align:center; ">

        <a id="inifiniteLoader"><img src="imagesoruce" /></a>

            <div style="clear:both"></div>

        </div> 

 <script type="text/javascript">

        var count = 2;

        var total = <?php ceil($total / $items_per_page)  ?>;


        jQuery(function($) {

            $('#loadmorebutton').click(function() {


                     if (count > total){

                 $('#loadmorebutton').hide();

                    $('#no_morebutton').show();

                return false;

                }else{

                        $('#loadmorebutton').hide();

                     $('a#inifiniteLoader').show();

                    loadArticle(count);

                 }

                 count++;



            })

        });

        function loadArticle(pageNumber){    

               jQuery.ajax({

                     url: "Yourpageurl"+pageNumber+"/",

                    type:'POST',                      

                    success: function(html){
                   result=    jQuery(html);

                        jQuery('a#inifiniteLoader').hide('1000');

                        jQuery('#loadmorebutton').show('1000');

                     jQuery("ul.commentsList").append(result.find("ul.commentsList").html());   // This will be the div where our content will 
                    }
                });

            return false;
                  }

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you Vijay Lal. I had to tweak a few things based on what I required, but that worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space before selector. This must be:

```
$('.commentsWrap').load(link + ' .commentsWrap');
```